# How to convert some commits in default to a branch?

Tags: mercurial

I am working on a project and started to work on a new feature some commits ago. Usually I would have created a branch out of `default` and merge it back in when done, like in this case for `consistant scan_uuid`:

[image]

I forgot to do this and I now realize that, since rev `411`, I should have started a new branch `delete old records`

[image]

Is it over? Is there a way to branch/rename `default` to `delete old records` between rev `411` and `413`? (let's imagine, to make the question more versatile, that I am now at rev `420` in `default` and would like to move only the portion between `411` and `413` to the `delete old records` branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read about rebase, grok it
2. Move part of history into new branch

   - create branch as child of 410 cset (*your* homework)
   - rebase `411::` to the new branch (*your* homework)
   - return `414::` back to default branch... and answer "why it's needed" (*your* homework)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try that. The  condescendent tone was useless, not everyone is born with universal knowledge.